# TypeError: jit_nodeValue_4(...).$any is not a function in angular 5

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular5

[image: While I run the code below attached image error occurred plz help to fix that error]

I have tried almost everything avalible. But I am not able to find any solution

[image: Order.component.html]

[image]

Comment: Can you also post OrderComponent.html?

Comment: yeah sure sir..

Comment: Post code not pictures

Comment: Please add code, then we maybe can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same issue in Angular 5 and I updated npm package by

```
npm update
```

and problem resolved for me, there was some issue in angular dependencies so I updated it.